# Check if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{\sqrt n}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, conditional-convergence

Check if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{\sqrt n}$ converges

So I think that the series is conditionally convergence that what I did so far

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\vert\frac{(-1)^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{\sqrt n}\vert>\frac{1}{n}$$
therefore by the comparison test the series diverges
but to prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{\sqrt n}$ is convergent I wanted to use the alternate series test but I don't think i can use that because the series dosn't alternate every term any idea of what am I missing here?

Comment: If your series starts with $n=1$ you can separate it into two series and use the *Leibniz's test* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 2):

Split the sum into two sums by $n\to 2n$ and $n\to 2n-1$ but consider only the first $Q$ terms

$\sum_{n=1}^Q\frac{(-1)^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}{\sqrt n}=\sum_{n=1}^{Q/2}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt {2n}}-
\sum_{n=1}^{Q/2}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt {2n-1}}$

$|{(-1)^n}/{\sqrt {2n-1}}|=1/{\sqrt {2n-1}}$ converge to $0$, and the two sums on the RHS are alternating. Hence the limit $Q\to\infty$ exist on the left hand side, and by equality for all $Q$ the limit also exist on the right hand side, so the sum in question is convergent. (and the limits are equal)

Comment: can you rearrange the terms like that for a series that is not absolutely convergent?

Comment: @LeonardBlackburn The terms of two convergent sums can be combined and the resulting sum is convergent.

Comment: @Coolwater "Combined" is not that clear a mathematical term. What Leonard asked you, I think, is whether you can **change** the summation order. We know we can do that with absolutely convergent series...but this series is **not** abs. convergent...

Comment: However he is simply considering convergence not whether they converge to the same value. I don’t know if that changes it.

Comment: @LeonardBlackburn if you are unsure, use the sequence of partial sums and show it converges  (using the approach above), there is no ambiguity there with partial sums. In short: this works because it's not an arbitrary, "funky" rearrangement.

Comment: @Coolwater I really am not sure, and in fact I personally think that what you did with the splitting of the sum is right because of the reason Will mentions...

Comment: @LeonardBlackburn Thank you I forgot all about that. I think rearrangement is always ok, if the old/new position of no term differ more than some finite bound.

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything, but you have powerful theorems to use, for example [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) . Can you spot what are $\;a_n,\,b_n\;$ here and whether the conditions are fulfilled?

Comment: Good test.Series will convergent no?

Comment: @omkarGirkar Indeed so.

Comment: @user90369 Nonsense: if $\;n=0\;$ was accepted the above is neither a series nor anything related to *actual* mathematics, as division by zero is undefined. Most probably that's merely a typo and the sum begins at $\;n=1\;$ .

Comment: That's what I want to point out. That's all.